# How to inject an anonymous inner class with dagger?

Tags: java, anonymous-inner-class, dagger

It's posible inject an anonymous class? I'm having the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No inject registered for members/com.acme.MyFragment$1. You must explicitly add it to the 'injects' option in one of your modules.

Example:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        new MyTrask(getActivity()) {
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                // Stuff
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}

public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Inject
    UserApi userApi;

    public MyTask(Context context) {
        App.getInstance().inject(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}
```

Comment: You do not implement a constructor. Furthermore - as far as I know - you cannot add parameters to a constructor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should inject the `AsyncTask` into `MyFragment` rather than using "new MyTask(..)". The `MyTask` constructor should take an `UserApi` instance and a `Context` object which can be provided by the module with code akin to;

```
  /**
   * The application module.
   *
   * @param context The context.
   */
  public MyModule(final Context context) {
    this.context = context.getApplicationContext();
  }

  /**
   * Provides context.
   *
   * @return the application context.
   */
  @Provides @Singleton Context provideContext() {
    return context;
  }
```

Your fragment code should then look like;

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
    @Inject Provider<MyTask> myTaskProvider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        inject(this);
        myTaskProvider.get().execute();
    }
}
```

And your AsyncTask API should be;

```
@Inject 
public MyTask(Context context, UserApi userApi) { }
```

Notice I used a `Provider` for the injection of the AsyncTask. This is necessary to avoid exceptions akin to "You can only execute a task once" that you would get if you called `execute` against the same AsyncTask object more than once. You then register `MyFragment` under your module `injects = { }` annotation arguments.

Comment: This will work. You could also just inject the `UserApi` into the fragment and pass it into the constructor of `MyTask`.

Comment: OceanLife thanks for your answer but it doesn't allow me to use anonymous class. I guess it's not possible, is it? I'll try your solution and the @JakeWharton solution.

Comment: That warm feeling when Jake agrees. Yep, either will work. The reason why I made it a "named" class is just personal preference- I prefer to make all my dependencies explicit so I can mock them out when I unit test. (Although binding Testing Modules is an alternative mocking solution) Cheers.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Surprisingly example like this is hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

You can't inject into an anonymous class. But you can do inject into the Fragment and it will be visible for the anonymous class, the AsyncTask in this case.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

 @Inject
 UserApi userApi;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    App.getInstance().inject(this);

    new MyTrask() {
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // Stuff
        }
    }.execute();
  }
}

 public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
    userApi.callAnyMethod(); // use userApi here
    return "Hello World!";
 }
}
```